# Junit for generateToken() method for JWT in Springboot

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
public String generateToken(final String id) {
    
    Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(id);
    long nowMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long expMillis = nowMillis + tokenValidity;
    Date exp = new Date(expMillis);
    
    return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setIssuedAt(new Date(nowMillis)).setExpiration(exp)
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact();
}
```

Now I want to write JUnit for this method and I am trying like below, but I am getting error

```
    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void test_generateToken() throws JwtTokenMalformedException, JwtTokenMissingException {
        final String subject_id = "123456789";
        final Long tokenValidity = 180000L;
        final String jwtSecret = "jwtSecret";

        when(Jwts.claims().setSubject(subject_id)).thenReturn(new DefaultClaims()); //** line no: 10
      
        when(Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setIssuedAt(new Date(nowMillis)).setExpiration(exp)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret).compact()).thenReturn(new String());
    }
```

getting error at line number 10:

> ```
> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
>     when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
>
> Also, this error might show up because:
> 1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
>    Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
>    Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
> 2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other >     object.
> ```

Comment: Can someone please suggest how to write testcases for this method ?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems need to be solved in your code: mocking static methods and multiple chained calls on a mocked object. Please, find the code with inline comments below as well as some references for further reading. Important note: `mockito-inline` should be used (see docs links below).

```java
void test_generateToken() {
    var tested = new TestedClass();
    var jwtSecret = "jwtSecret";
    var claims = new DefaultClaims();
    var mockedValue = "mocked value";
    var builder = mock(Jwts.JwtsBuilder.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);

    try (var mockedStatic = mockStatic(Jwts.class)) {
        // to mock static methods the object returned from the mockStatic method should be used
        mockedStatic.when(Jwts::claims)
                    .thenReturn(claims);
        mockedStatic.when(Jwts::builder)
                    .thenReturn(builder);
        // here we're not mocking static methods, so a standard when method is used
        // thanks to RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS we can mock a chain of method calls
        when(builder.setClaims(claims)
                    // other argument matchers like argThat() can be used here
                    .setIssuedAt(any())
                    .setExpiration(any())
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
                    .compact())
                .thenReturn(mockedValue);

        var result = tested.generateToken("value");

        assertEquals(mockedValue, result);
    }
}
```

- [mockStatic method docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#mockStatic-java.lang.Class-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-)
- [example of static mocking from the docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#static_mocks)
- [RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS docs](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.4.3/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
- [ArgumentMatchers docs (see: any(), argThat())](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.3.3/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html)
- [mockito-inline docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#39)

I've created [a commit in a GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/ac8a0e477060a6ffa12a30efdf49ac04315eb60a), where you can find the code above as well as `mockito-inline` dependency reference and a few fake classes representing the missing code from your question (which is not important as it's all mocked). The test shown in the example passes.